# Vertical menu expanding is not working for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried a sample of Vertical menu from [CSSmenu](http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/modern-jquery-accordion-menu) site, sample source code working and menu is expanding as per the sample, when i try to add the menu dynamically, those menu's are not expanding even i have verified the final object structure.

Code with dynamic menu:

```
<body>
    <script>
        /**
         * Comment
         */
        function add() {
            var list = document.getElementById('list');
            var elem=document.createElement('li');
            elem.setAttribute('class','last has-sub');
            elem.innerHTML="<a href='#'><span>My_Products</span></a>"
                +"<ul style='display: none;' >"
                    +"<li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>"
                    +"<li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>"
                    +"<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>"
               + "</ul>";
       list.appendChild(elem);
        }
    </script>
    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul id='list'>
            <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Product 3</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
            <li class='last has-sub'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Add Menu" onclick="add()">
</body>
```

Comment: Share respective CSS too..

Comment: A jsfiddle link would be more better.

Comment: **Edited**: _script.js_ from this "library" has line: `$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {`. Replace it with `$('#cssmenu').on('click', '#list > li > a', function() {`

Comment: @Regent, your idea worked, but why this change required even if the dynamic menu comes under the same `<div id='cssmenu'> <ul id='list'>` and problem is coming only for new menus, but now its working thanks

Comment: @jerith2 due to `$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(`, `click` event will not be handled with this handler for newly created elements. That's why delegated event handler is required here. Why author of library didn't do it in this way - I don't know.

Comment: @Regent , yes! very clear now thanks !

Comment: @jerith2 you're welcome. Since the problem is solved, you can delete the question,  or I can post my comment as an answer, if you are ready to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*script.js* in this "library" has line:

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
```

So dynamically created elements will not be handled with this `click` handler. You can modify script's line, transforming this handler into [delegated event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$('#cssmenu').on('click', '#list > li > a', function() {
```